# Need to add custom attribute along with order

Tags: orders, custom-attributes

I need to set custom `attribute` along with `order`,

This attribute will have random values with each order,  I need to  show this value on the sales/order grid in admin.

Comment: this useful to you http://fabrizioballiano.net/2011/11/15/create-a-custom-order-attribute-in-magento/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom php file with this code, and put in your root folder of magento.

And run the file by url.

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'backend_type'  => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'         => 'Your attribute label',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,   
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'default'       => ''
);
$attribute2  = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'backend_type'  => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'         => 'Your attribute label',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,   
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'placed_order_by', $attribute);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'related_recurring', $attribute2);
$installer->endSetup();`enter code here`
```

Comment: And also this line in your config.xml

Comment: <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
            <placed_order_by>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </placed_order_by>
            <related_recurring>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </related_recurring>
        </sales_convert_quote>
    </fieldsets>